# Loading a Map in field of Class Object, before the Class instance is returned by getBean method of Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a .properties file having 10  key-values pairs say age =10, name=Jon etc. I have configured a bean in spring which has a map as a member variable.

When the bean is loaded by Spring once I call the getBean method, before that the Map should be loaded with the properties from files. How to do that ?

I know this should be done in one of the lifecycle methods like afterPropertiesSet using InitializingBean or init-method configuration. Is there any other better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable annotations in your beans:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Then you can define method with `@PostConstruct` annotation. Spring will execute it during bean initialization process:

```
class MyBean {
    private Map<String, String> properties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        // read properties and initialize map
    }
}
```

Another option is to inject `Properties` directly into your bean and provide map-like API to access them:

```
<util:properties id="myProperties" location="classpath:my-props.properties">
<bean id="myBean" class="com.example.MyBean">
    <property name="properties" ref="myProperties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use context property-placeholder within XML spring configuration file using ${...} or from java class configuration file using @value.